# Unable to use flutter device preview package || No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'

Tags: flutter

Platform -

```
Flutter 1.24.0-10.2.pre • channel dev • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 022b333a08 (8 days ago) • 2020-11-18 11:35:09 -0800
Engine • revision 07c1eed46b
Tools • Dart 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-29.10.beta)
```

SRC -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      DevicePreview(
        builder: (context) => MyApp(), // Wrap your app
      ),
    );

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      locale: DevicePreview.locale(context), // Add the locale here
      builder: DevicePreview.appBuilder, // Add the builder here
      home: Text("Home Page"),
    );
  }
}
```

Error -

```
Running "flutter pub get" in xyz...
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.5.5/lib/src/views/device_preview_style.dart:86:42: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
    final media = MediaQuery.of(context, nullOk: true) ??
                                         ^^^^^^
../../../../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/media_query.dart:814:25: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static MediaQueryData of(BuildContext context) {
                        ^^
Failed to compile application.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Tried on a Pixel device also, doesn't work.

Opened issue - https://github.com/aloisdeniel/flutter_device_preview/issues/91

Comment: The device_preview package doesn't work on the web. There's an open issue about Flutter Web not supporting path drawing

Comment: Tried on device also, doesn't work.

Comment: Did you set enabled = true?

Comment: Yes, tried that as well.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this issue was that Flutter removed the `nullOk` parameter in MediaQuery that's being used by the [device_preview](https://pub.dev/packages/device_preview) plugin as mentioned on this [issue thread](https://github.com/aloisdeniel/flutter_device_preview/issues/91#issuecomment-735256149). An update for the plugin has been rolled out to fix the issue.